# Conditional Data fetch for a specific time window with SQL IF Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, conditional-statements

I have the below scenario. I have a table(name mytab1) in mysql database(using workbench community 6.3) which consists of columns like **id, message and incidentdate(which is a date-time type)**. Mytab1 can contain more than 10k data. Now my requirement is to fetch the data by below condition :

**Edit : 
if{incidentdate < (current_systime - 2 hours)}** 
then fetch all the records from the table.

Else fetch  **the record**  whose incidentdate < (current_systime - 5 minutes).

I have used the below syntax for the same :

```
select if((select timestampdiff(minute,incidentdate,now()) from mytab1)>120,
(select message from mytab1),
(select message from mytab1 where incidentdate < date_add(now(), interval -5 minutes))) 
as message;
```

Now, for the very first instance my table mytab1 contains below data :

```
id, message, incidentdate
-------------------------
A01, Incident_01, 2016-02-08 20:00:30
A02, Incident_02, 2016-02-08 20:10:20
```

conditional SQL query should able to fetch the above two data(as it is beyond two hours of current system time i.e. 2016-02-09 01:00:10). Now in the second instance a new data(one row for example) has entered in mytab1 table and mytab1 looks like below :

```
id, message, incidentdate
-------------------------
A01, Incident_01, 2016-02-08 20:00:30
A02, Incident_02, 2016-02-08 20:10:20
A03, Incident_03, 2016-02-09 00:55:30
```

And with this new data conditional SQL query should able to fetch data for complete third row only having message as "Incident_03".

With the above mentioned syntax of SQL query I am not able to fetch the data if there are multiple row in mytab1 and also not working if I want to fetch all the columns of mytab1 table. Would you kindly help with the conditional SQL syntax for this requirement please.

Comment: So these are incidents that happen in the future?

Comment: Yes, mytab1 will get new data every minute.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I asked you to confirm that stored incidents occur in the future - as your question implies.

Comment: Ok, no all the incident will be unique, i.e. "Incident_03" won't happen again  in future. There will be a new Incident for example "Incident_04" and that record will come to mytab1. And id column would be primary key for mytab1.

Comment: You misunderstand. The time now is 20:10. If we were to look at the table now, might we find an incident at 22:15, say?

Comment: No, the incidentdate value will not be greater than system date-time value for a particular time. The requirement is to fetch all the data for the first instance, i.e. first time transaction. From then onward, we need to fetch the delta data only. The above data is just for illustration purpose only.

Comment: `if(incidentdate >= current_systime+2 hours)` means a time 2 hours in the future.

Comment: Updated the condition. Thank you.